# How to write a ColdFusion variable an HTML meta tag

Tags: coldfusion

I have a share to Facebook button on a page that displays obituaries.

This site is coded in ColdFusion. What I am trying to do is pass the `obituarietitle` variable to the meta tag `og:description` like so:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="#obituarietitle#">
```

Through using the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ everything is showing up except the description which would be the name of the person who has passed.

The "share" shows `#obituarietitle#` the variable.I have tried cfoutput tags, cfsets, ect.

I am not seasoned with ColdFusion or og:, I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: If surrounding the variable in a `cfoutput` doesn't work, then either you don't have ColdFusion installed, or the requested page the code is on isn't a `.cfm` page so CF isn't rendering it.

Answer (score 3):

You must be in a cfoutput region to write variable contents to the output HTML.

So this would work:

```
<cfoutput>
<meta property="og:description" content="#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(obituarietitle)#">
</cfoutput>
```

Note the `EncodeForHTMLAttribute()` - calling this function is necessary to ensure that the value will not break your markup if it contains HTML-specific characters.

It is also a **security precaution** that prevents [HTML injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). Make sure you use this function on all variable values that you output.

---

**Edit:** `EncodeForHTMLAttribute()` is a cousin of the [`EncodeForHTML()` function](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforhtml.html), member of a group of functions designed to format ColdFusion values in such a way that they are suitable to be used safely in various contexts.

Comment: `HTMLEditFormat` is deprecated in ColdFusion 10, use `encodeForHTMLAttribute` instead

Comment: @John Oh, nice to know! I have not looked at the docs for that function in a long time, the deprecation notice slipped under my radar. I'm a bit uncertain though what where the effective, practical difference between `HTMLEditFormat` and `EncodeForHTMLAttribute` is. The docs are not helpful, can you add any insight?

Comment: For the difference between the two, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597073/encodeforhtml-vs-htmleditformat

Comment: I tried <cfoutput><meta property="og:description" content="#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(obituarietitle)#"></cfoutput> 

It broke my site, here is the error:
An error occurred at #DateFormat( Now(), "mmm d, yyyy" )# at #TimeFormat( Now(), "hh:mm TT" )#
Error
CGI
REQUEST
FORM
URL
SESSION
mail sent mail not sent

My file does end in .cfm - it is however a template file so .dwt.cfm where the meta tags are located-- not sure if that is an issue??

Comment: This looks like a new question. You should ask a new question with the revised code